# Polynomial with degree 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Can somebody help me with this problem ? Thank you !

> Let $f$ a polynomial function with $\deg(f) = 3$ and $\alpha < \beta$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that equations $f(x) = \alpha$ and $f(x) = \beta$ have all zeros distinct and real.
>   Show the pre-image of the interval $[\alpha, \beta]$ through $f$ is reunion of $3$ disjoint intervals, one of them having the length equal with sum of length of the others.

$\text{My approach:}$

I used $f = aX^3 + bX^2 + cX + d$ and tried to get something from hypothesis but i don't get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the cubic have equation $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where, without loss of generality, suppose $a>0$. Let the roots of $y=\alpha$ be $r<s<t$ and of $y=\beta$ be $u<v<w$.

Since $a>0$ the three required intervals are $[r,u],[v,s]$ and $[t,w]$ and are clearly disjoint. (Draw a sketch of the cubic to see what is happening.)

The roots $r,s,t$ satisfy $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d-\alpha=0$ and so the sum of the roots satisfy
$r+s+t=-\frac{b}{a}$. Similarly for $u,v,w$. Therefore $$u+v+w=r+s+t.$$
Then $$(u-r)+(w-t)=(v-s)$$ which is the required result.